# Why is RegExp.prototype a /(?:)/, when Boolean.prototype is a Boolean {}?

Tags: javascript, prototype, ecmascript-5

Environment:
- Chrome console

I understand:

```
Boolean.prototype;  // Boolean {}
Number.prototype;  // Number {}
```

I can't understand:

```
RegExp.prototype;  // /(?:)/
```

Question:

- `RegExp` is different, why?
- The method is determined, which is called by default toString of `Date.prototype`(like) it?

Comment: I'd imagine it is because RegExp is almost completely natively implemented in most browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeing a behavior of the Chrome console. It's showing you the value of `RegExp.prototype.toString()` which returns that regular expression.

Comment: Why. ToString () method will be called? 
Specification?

Comment: @user3474300 [check the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log). Where it says that the "string representations" of the objects are printed, that means that it's calling `.toString()`. You can check that yourself by creating an object with your own version of `.toString()` that does something interesting.